# Shrink Volume of Hard Disk Containing Recovery Partition

Tags: windows, windows-10, hard-drive, partitioning, recovery-partition

I just bought a new Lenovo IdeaPad 320, with Windows 10 pre-installed with two normal partitions (`C:` and `D:`) and One Key Recovery Partition. Size of `C:` drive is too large, also I want to create other partition to manage my data easily.

Here is the complete details of partitions:

1. 260 MB EFI System Partition
2. 905 GB Windows `C:`
3. 25GB Lenovo (Drivers) `D:`
4. 1000MB Recovery Partition

I want to reduce size of `C:` drive and want make two new partitions from space reduced from `C:` drive, *without affecting* the Recovery Partition, which is located at last of holding size of 1000 MB.

How can I do it without affecting my Reovery Partition? If I shrink `C:` drive volume, and create other drives, will it affect Recovery Partition?

Comment: Shrink the C partition and create a new partition with the unallocated space.

Comment: You indicated you had a separate recovery partition.  I am not sure the reason you have a 1 TB recovery partition, seems excessive, considering it sounds like you don't even have a windows recovery partition.  Besides you indicated you wanted to shrink the C partition, so doing so, is the only way to do that.

Comment: So shrink the partition that contains Windows and delete the driver partition (drivers can be downloaded on the internet) then create the partitions you want.  Update your question and delete your comment

Comment: FYI windows 10 doesn't need a separate recovery partition to be able to do a factory reset. I also believe that no OEM creates such a giant recovery partition unless the user explicitly expand it

Comment: First you take a backup of your system with Macrium reflect backup with macrium reflect 
https://knowledgebase.macrium.com/display/KNOW/How+backup+sets+are+created+and+maintained
 free version image entire system on an external 1.5 TB usb, then use a partition manager like AOMEI partition assistant or any other partititon manager of your choice also check the tutorial here 
shrink partitions in windows 10
https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/96288-shrink-volume-partition-windows-10-a.html
 tenforums is a much better place for these kind of questions.

Comment: backup and restore with macrium reflector
https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/61026-backup-restore-macrium-reflect.html you are lucky your question did not got downvoted or closed being marked as duplicate other wise every new comer who asks questions is thrown out of the forum be it stackoverflow or stackexchange group of sites [link](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/340972/why-cant-a-publicly-accessible-image-not-be-posted-when-i-press-fetch-image) any how that is not the point just visit tenforums.com once you will find a lot of good tutorials and resources there.

Answer (score 1):

Open start menu, Disk Management
Select the partition from the list and select shrink volume from the menu.
It will allow you to shink the file system down to as small as it can be made without running into unmovable files.

Once the partition has shrunk it will make unallocated space available after it. According to your layout this will be before your drivers and recovery partitions. Create a new partition here then format it then "Change driver letter or path" to assign it.

Answer (score 1):

Right-click “Computer”-> “Manage”-> double click “Disk Management”,  right-click the C drive, select “Shrink Partition”. It will query volume for available shrink space.

[image: screenshot]

Then, type in the amount of space that you want to shrink by, then the unallocated space will be next to C drive.

Create a new partition based on the unallocated space.

Comment: This duplicates [jdwolf's answer](https://superuser.com/a/1259112/432690) from three years ago, which is quite clear even without a screenshot. In my opinion your answer adds nothing new.